# Check collision between two Rects from different classes

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I have two classes, the first one is Foo and has coordinates, velocity and functions to it, the second is Balloon and has similar stuff in it. I want to check the collision between them, I have the collision_check function working just right and it DOESN'T belong to any class. Both classes( Foo and Balloon ) have their coordinates defined in their respective class. First way: I tried to put their SDL_Rects in their classes too, but when I call collision_check in main(), it can't find the SDL_Rects because they are in the classes. Second way: So I tried to put the SDL_Rects and define them in the main(), but then I can't assign the coordinates of the foos to them, cuz the coordinate variables are in the classes. Third way: then I tried to move the coordinates variables out of the class, but then all the functions dont work cuz they are in the classes too. How can I use the collide_check function.....I'm stuck. Try to explain it simply for someone who's been coding for less than 4 months.

Comment: This is one of those cases where abstraction should take precedence. You've identified something common between the classes (they can collide), therefore you should create that abstract class and ensure each object inherits from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an "AbstractCollisionObject" type which is an abstract class. 
Then inherit it to create BoundingBoxCollisionObject and CircleCollisionObject.

In your function collision_check, you take the 2 AbstractCollisionObjects and do the tests.

Each one of your elements that you handle in your scene should have one AbstractCollisionObject assiociated.

Comment: I disagree about this requiring the creation of BoundingBoxCollisionObject and CircleCollisionObject. There's no need to make a convoluted inheritance tree; OP just needs to implement the AbstractCollisionObject interface within Foo and Balloon.

Comment: The day he adds another element in his scene, he will have to handle that collision too and will have to duplicate code. DRY thx

Comment: Guys, this stuff is too complicated - inheritance, virtual and abstract classes and stuff. I want a semi-simple 2D game...And I just came up with an idea and decided to ask here first. What's gonna happen if I make a function of type SDL_Rect in class foo and use the function just to return the coordinates of my SDL_Rect box. For example:
SDL_Rect Foo::get_coordinates()
{
    return box;   //The box.x, box.y, box.w and box.h
}
But I need to return this stuff for every frame and I was wondering if performance is going to be a problem later on...

Comment: But I wanted to ask it here, because nobody suggested this so there must be something wrong with it...Tell me all the pros and cons.

Comment: @Bogdan: you don't have the choice, you will somewhere to access these datas. If you think you will have to handle several hundred of elements, you won't be able to do each collision test: you will have to add quadtree. The solution I gave you is one I used in one of my project, and it helped a lot.

Comment: And don't think that it's even if it's a 2D game that you can't do stuff that complicated. When you will have hundred elements in the scene, if you don't have that, you will have a nightmare when looking at your code.